# Delete the rows with no continuous occurrence of a column values of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2    col3 
 1        A       P
 2        B       P
 3        C       P
 4        D       P
 5        E       Q
 6        F       T
 7        G       T
 8        H       T
 9        I       P
 10       J       Q
 11       K       Q
```

I want to create a data frame frame from above with following condition,
If the col3 value is not repetitive (the above or bottom row of col3 value is not same) delete that particular row, here row 5 has only Q and row 9 has only P so these rows should be deleted.

so the final data frame should look like,

```
col1    col2    col3 
 1        A       P
 2        B       P
 3        C       P
 4        D       P
 6        F       T
 7        G       T
 8        H       T
 10       J       Q
 11       K       Q
```

I could do this using a for loop and iterating with the next rows, but using it the execution time will be more. Looking for some pandas shortcuts/ pythonic way to do this task most efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `col3` to consecutive groups and then filter by duplicated groups created by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df['col3'].ne(df['col3'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)
```

Or if want select by counts here is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and compare for greater like `1`:

```
mask=df['col3'].groupby(df['col3'].ne(df['col3'].shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').gt(1)
```

Similar solution with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df['col3'].ne(df['col3'].shift()).cumsum()
mask = s.map(s.value_counts()).gt(1)

df = df[mask]
print (df)
    col1 col2 col3
0      1    A    P
1      2    B    P
2      3    C    P
3      4    D    P
5      6    F    T
6      7    G    T
7      8    H    T
9     10    J    Q
10    11    K    Q
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using shift, essentially you want to exclude something which is flanked by values not itself, so the complementary of that is:

```
df[(df['col3'] == df['col3'].shift(-1)) | (df['col3'] == df['col3'].shift(1))]

   col1 col2 col3
0   1   A   P
1   2   B   P
2   3   C   P
3   4   D   P
5   6   F   T
6   7   G   T
7   8   H   T
9   10  J   Q
10  11  K   Q
```

This will include single values at the 1st and last line.. not very sure how you want to deal with those...